# Get sub-tweets with snscrape

Tags: python, twitter

i try to get the "sub-tweets" from this link:
https://twitter.com/M4573RCH/status/1659780009266122753

I try to get the informations using the following code:

from snscrape.modules.twitter import TwitterTweetScraper

```
from snscrape.modules.twitter import TwitterTweetScraper
tweet = TwitterTweetScraper("1659780009266122753")
for i, item in enumerate(tweet.get_items()):
  print(item.url)
  print(item.content)
  print(item.retweetCount)
```

But it seems with that code i only get the tweet "itself".
But not the "sub-tweets" from this link.

See attached in the red rectangle what i want to have:

[image]